# C# float to string separator

Tags: c#, localization

I am new to C # and I am currently having problems with the following. In C #, I have a Pi floating point number and I want to convert it to a string using the `ToString()` method. But the conversion gives a string result with a comma "3,1415". On another machine, the same gives the string result with the dot "3.1415". What is the reason for this and what should I do to get a dotted string result?

**EDIT**: The problem is, I can't change the code, but I can install and uninstall .Net frameworks, change my OS settings, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to GSerg, for comment about Windows regional settings. That solves my problem. In the Windows Control panel enter Region and Language. In the Formats tab click Additional Settings and in the Decimal symbol field specify what decimal separator must be used when converting a floating point number to a string.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: if you can't change the code. Change the language/localization of the system to one which uses dot as decimal separator. In Control Panel or Settings.

You should look at internationalization and localization in the `System.Globalization` namespace.

The advice here is to use one CultureInfo specific for parsing numbers or writing numbers to string.

```
var flt = 232.23f;

var str = flt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //for example, you can use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

This allows you to keep the ThreadCulture without change it.

But take a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0 .Take your time, is dense.

Comment: `Usually` not. More than half the world uses `,` as the decimal separator. China is the biggest country that uses `.`. The *best choice* is to do nothing and use the *end user's locale* for both parsing and formatting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos edited. In addition, My country use comma (Spain)

Comment: I edited the question. I cannot change the code.

Comment: Change the windows language/culture in panel control or settings>language and keyboard

Comment: @VahagChakhoyan but what is the actual problem? The code looks to be behaving just fine. Numbers in the US and UK are displayed differently. *Your users* expect the application to display numbers and *dates* in their locale's format.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with you. The question only had sense if you should/can change the code.

Comment: @DrkDeveloper I'm not sure the code needs changing. This looks more like a misunderstanding of localization

Comment: What can I do to get the result as a dotted string without changing the code?

Comment: @VahagChakhoyan I told you, change your pc language to a zone where they use dot as a decimal separator

Comment: That's why even Java developer (like me) hate c# ...

Answer (score -2):

I would just set the current culture at the entry point of your program.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
```

However I would also check the regional settings and so forth on the machine where the comma separator appears.

Comment: I edited the question. I cannot change the code.

Answer (score -2):

It is related with current [culture info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-5.0). You can specify the culture info in ToString method as a parameter like;

```
var convertedFloat = floatVariable.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: I edited the question. I cannot change the code.